# How to put texts in image via WordCloud in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

I have a problem about showing texts put in image via WordCloud in Jupyter Notebook.

Here is my image shown below.

[image]

The output of figure is based on the results of text in rectangle not showing in defined text in image.

Here is the output

[image]

How can I fix it?

Here is my code snippet defined below.

```
plt.figure(figsize=[15,15])

char_mask = np.array(Image.open("images/netflix.png"))
image_colors = ImageColorGenerator(char_mask)

wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,background_color = 'white', 
                      width = 1000,  
                      height = 1000, 
                      max_words =300,
                      mask=char_mask).generate(' '.join(netflix_df['title']))

wordcloud.recolor(color_func=image_colors)

plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Most Popular Words in Title',fontsize = 30)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. Maybe show expected result.

Comment: @furas There is a problem in result. The output is based on words in rectangle not put words in text.

Comment: I don't understand what "rectangle" you mean. I don't see any variable `rectangle` in code. Maybe show in question image with result you get and show image which you expect.

Comment: @furas I editted my post.

Comment: if you want to put text only inside `NETFLIX` then you have to create image with black `NETFLIX` on white background. See image in wordcloud documentation: [masked](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/masked.html) - it is black on white background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put result inside word `NETFLIX` then create black `NETFLIX` on white background.

It is easier to do it in any photo editor (like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) or `Photoshop`)

(BTW: I added `contour_width=` and `contour_color=` to see if code found `NETFLIX` on image)

Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

netflix_df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['King Kong', 'Rambo', 'Rambo II', 'Rambo III', 'James Bond',]})
text = ' '.join(netflix_df['title']

char_mask = np.array(Image.open("netflix.png")) # black NETFLIX on white background

wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                        background_color='white', 
                        #width=1000,  
                        #height=1000, 
                        max_words=300,
                        mask=char_mask,
                        contour_width=3, 
                        contour_color='steelblue',
                    ).generate(text))

#image_colors = ImageColorGenerator(np.array(image))
#wordcloud.recolor(color_func=image_colors)

plt.figure(figsize=[15, 15])
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Most Popular Words in Title', fontsize=30)
plt.show()
```

Documentation: [Masked wordcloud](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/masked.html)

---

With your original image (red `NETFLIX` on black bacground) you can try to convert to grayscale and invert it.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

image = Image.open("netflix.jpg") # red NETFLIX on white background
image_gray = image.convert('L')
image_invert = ImageOps.invert(image_gray)
#image_invert.show() # it shows result
char_mask = np.array(image_invert)

#im = Image.fromarray(char_mask)
#im.show()
```

But original `jpg` image has many different values for red color and mask is not perfect.

[image]

It needs more work - ie. filter colors in ranges.

```
char_mask[ char_mask < 200 ] = 0
char_mask[ char_mask > 200 ] = 255
```

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

netflix_df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['King Kong', 'Rambo', 'Rambo II', 'Rambo III', 'James Bond',]})
text = ' '.join(netflix_df['title']

image = Image.open("netflix.jpg") # red NETFLIX on black background
image_gray = image.convert('L')
image_invert = ImageOps.invert(image_gray)
#image_invert.show()
char_mask = np.array(image_invert)
char_mask[ char_mask < 200 ] = 0
char_mask[ char_mask > 200 ] = 255
#print(char_mask)

#im = Image.fromarray(char_mask)
#im.show()

wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                        background_color='white', 
                        #width=1000,  
                        #height=1000, 
                        max_words=300,
                        mask=char_mask,
                        contour_width=3, 
                        contour_color='steelblue',
                    ).generate(text))

image_colors = ImageColorGenerator(np.array(image))
wordcloud.recolor(color_func=image_colors)

plt.figure(figsize=[15,15])
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Most Popular Words in Title',fontsize = 30)
plt.show()
```

---

**BTW:** if you create white `NETFLIX` on black background

[image]

Then you can get

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

netflix_df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['King Kong', 'Rambo', 'Rambo II', 'Rambo III', 'James Bond',]})
text = ' '.join(netflix_df['title']

image = Image.open("netflix.jpg") # red NETFLIX on black background
image_gray = image.convert('L')
#image_gray.show()
char_mask = np.array(image_gray)
char_mask[ char_mask < 50 ] = 0
char_mask[ char_mask > 50 ] = 255
print(char_mask)

#im = Image.fromarray(char_mask)
#im.show()

wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS,
                        background_color='white', 
                        #width=1000,  
                        #height=1000, 
                        max_words=300,
                        mask=char_mask,
                        contour_width=3, 
                        contour_color='steelblue',
                    ).generate(text))

image_colors = ImageColorGenerator(np.array(image))
wordcloud.recolor(color_func=image_colors)

plt.figure(figsize=[15,15])
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Most Popular Words in Title',fontsize = 30)
plt.show()
```

---

**BTW:** to invert gray scale image you can also use

```
char_mask = ~char_mask  # invert gray scale
```